# How to get CSS working on a PHP file that has HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter

I have a php file that has html on it. There are stylesheets linked to the head of the file. When the script of the page is built and previewed what results is the page with the html and php content however the styling sheets are not being recognized in this page. Has anyone else found difficulty with getting the complete effects of a page that has html, php and css?

I am running this project on Visual Studio using a plugin called PHP Tools for VS.

Comment: Share the complete code

Comment: any errors in your browser console ? files not found or something like that ?

Comment: @JacobGoh yes there is 404 errors for the file not being found in their respective directory.